# How do we construct cayley tables for fields without using Lagrange's Theorem?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, field-theory, cayley-table

I'm just learning about sets, groups and fields, and I'm not sure how I'd go about making the addition cayley table for a field with, say, 4 or 5 elements. I know that, for example, 0 plus any element is the element itself, so for example:

[image: Field with 4 elements]

But then I'm stuck. Assuming I don't know things like Lagrange's theorem (not about to prove that for a homework when I haven't even learnt about cosets n stuff). I've also heard about things like Galois field and how they're applicable to stuff like this, but I only know the very basics, and so I'm not sure what the next step would be. For example, why couldn't there be two different cayley tables for a field with 4 element:

[image: Example 1 of a field cayley table I tried to construct]

and

[image: Example 2 of a field cayley table I tried to construct]

Which one is violating a field axiom? I'm a bit unclear on this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Think about $(1+1)a$.

Comment: Do you know what the characteristic of a field is? If yes, can you recall some basic facts about it?

Answer (score 1):

If one operation only is defined in your set, then you are in the realm of *groups*. To build up the Cayley table of a (finite...) group, you need to know how the operation "acts" on any *pair* ($2$-tuple) of elements of the set. Try with the set of the integers modulo $4$ with the operation $+$ (mod $4$), and then with set  of the Cartesian product of two copies of the integers modulo $2$ with the addition component-wise (mod $2$).